# Why does data.table recycle matrices into a single vector when data.frame does not?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, data.table

Compare the behavior of `data.table` and `data.frame` below:

```
a.matrix <- matrix(seq_len(25),ncol = 5, nrow = 5)

a.list <- list(seq_len(5),a.matrix)

a.dt <- as.data.table(a.list)
a.df <- as.data.frame(a.list)
a.dt.df <- as.data.table(a.df)

str(a.dt)
str(a.df)
str(a.dt.df)
```

`data.table` recycles the columns of the matrix into a vector of appropriate length:

```
> str(a.dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  25 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ V2: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

On the other hand, `data.frame` breaks each column out:

```
> str(a.df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X1.5: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ X1  : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ X2  : int  6 7 8 9 10
 $ X3  : int  11 12 13 14 15
 $ X4  : int  16 17 18 19 20
 $ X5  : int  21 22 23 24 25
```

My current workaround to get this behavior quickly with `as.data.table` is just to feed it through both `as` coercers:

```
> str(a.dt.df)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X1.5: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ X1  : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ X2  : int  6 7 8 9 10
 $ X3  : int  11 12 13 14 15
 $ X4  : int  16 17 18 19 20
 $ X5  : int  21 22 23 24 25
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Why is there a difference, and is there a fast way to get the `data.frame` behavior with `data.table`?

Comment: You could compare `as.data.table(do.call(cbind, a.list))`.

Comment: The coersion to `data.frame` and `data.table` is very different. Check `get("as.data.table.list",envir=environment(data.table))` to see how a list is corced to a `data.table` and try also for instance `as.data.table(list(seq_len(5),list(a.matrix)))` and compare to `as.data.frame`. All in all, it seems that the base `as.data.frame` is much smarter than `as.data.table` and the latter should be used just for data.frames.

Comment: Hm, it shouldn't. It should behave like `as.data.frame(.)` for consistency (unless there are strong arguments against). I guess this use case never really occurred before, so we dint have a test to catch it. Could you please file an issue [here](github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)? Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @arun, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071883/evalcall-different-from-typing-the-expression-into-the-console

Comment: For reference, the bug report: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this on the SO end, as mentioned in the comments, this is being handled as a [bug/issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/833) at github now, added to data.table milestone v1.9.8 of this writing.

---

#### Follow-up

This is now resolved as per [commit 64f377...](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/64f377bde1b617ec10be1a9b1bd5ac155ff56607)